# After drawing bounding rectangle on map, drawing another rectangle does not delete previous rectangle

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I created a function that draws a bounding rectangle on the map.  When I use create a new rectangle function that comes with leaflet the manually drawn rectangle is not cleared.  How to clear the manually drawn rectangle when someone uses the create new rectangle?

```
function drawRectangle()
```

{

```
var north = document.getElementById("north").value;
 var west = document.getElementById("west").value;
var east = document.getElementById("east").value;
var south = document.getElementById("south").value;
 var lat_lon = [[north,east],[south,west]];

  var rectangle = L.rectangle(lat_lon, { draggable: true ,redraw:true});
  rectangle.addTo(map);
 map.fitBounds(rectangle.getBounds());
}
```

[Manually Added Rectangle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lhv5sa8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare rectangle outside of the drawRectangle function you can remove it from the map before you draw the next rectangle:

```
var rectangle;
function drawRectangle()
{
  if(rectangle)
    rectangle.remove(map)

  var north = document.getElementById("north").value;
  var west = document.getElementById("west").value;
  var east = document.getElementById("east").value;
  var south = document.getElementById("south").value;
  var lat_lon = [[north,east],[south,west]];

  rectangle = L.rectangle(lat_lon, { draggable: true ,redraw:true});
  rectangle.addTo(map);
  map.fitBounds(rectangle.getBounds());
}
```

Or if you want it to be removed when you click the rectangle button put that logic in the event handler:

```
map.on('editable:drawing:move', function (e) { 
  if(rectangle)
    rectangle.remove(map)
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I tried both of these and was getting errors.  But I could have been on the incorrect fiddle.  Thanks again for your help.